# Direct Unity Firebase code to different google-services.json files

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I have two Firebase projects (one for development and one for production) and in my Assets folder I created two folders for each respectively where each contains its google-services.json file.
I have already wrote directives to read specific values for the API authentication and info such as following and fill the strings accordingly:

```
#if DEVELOPMENT_BUILD || UNITY_EDITOR
        public static string apiKey = "";
        public static string authDomain = "";
        public static string databaseURL = "";
        public static string projectId = "";
        public static string storageBucket = "";
        public static string messagingSenderId = "";
#else
        public static string apiKey = "";
        .
        . so on
#endif
```

But my storage reads the data directly from the instance which if I understood correctly takes the info from the JSON as it gave me an error that my bucket links do not match.
I am now unsure how to make it read from specific folders in each case, I have seen solutions to change the build.gradle files by adding project flavours but the file says it is generated by Unity and will get overwritten in the next build. All other answers I have seen suggested using FirebaseApp class and call for the Create function to use my own FirebaseOptions but I am not sure when to call the method and if there is a better way.

Additional Firebase code:

```
private Firebase()
        {
            authenticationPath = new URI("https://www.googleapis.com");
            databasePath = new URI(APIConfig.databaseURL);
        }
```

storage initialization:

```
 private FBStorage()
    {
        storage = Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
#if DEVELOPMENT_BUILD || UNITY_EDITOR
        root_storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://...");
#else
        root_storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://...");
#endif
    }
```

And the Firebasestorage class is sealed.

Comment: Can you show how you initialize Firebase in your application code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have provided the code that initializes the main Firebase class as well as the FBStorage class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `DefaultInstance` of `FirebaseStorage`, which also means you're using the default instance of `FirebaseApp` and that reads from the configuration files.

Instead, you'll want to create your own `FirebaseApp` instance by calling [`FirebaseApp.Create(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firebase-app#class_firebase_1_1_firebase_app_1aaeb3418d9c118fcb63a409ee05a5e4aa) and pass in the correct options for the current build there.

Then you can get a `FirebaseStorage` instance for *that* configured `FirebaseApp` by calling [`FirebaseStorage.getInstance(app, "gs://yourBucketUrl")`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/storage/firebase-storage#class_firebase_1_1_storage_1_1_firebase_storage_1a8a4cf4c5a660256ca31ca398d5680077).

Comment: Do I create the app options by calling the AppOptions.LoadFromJsonConfig function and send it my json/s folder path?